# Why am I getting 'undefined is not a function' on a simple js script?

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on the getElementByClassName line.

```
<script src="AnimOnScroll.js"></script>
    <script>
      new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementByClassName( 'container' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
      } );
    </script>
```

My question is, did I just make a simple syntax error here, or is the problem deeper than that?

I'm also curious if 'container' should be '.container' ?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is plural

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

Change `document.getElementByClassName`

To `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: oh my lord i got about 10 new errors after i fixed that.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName( 'container' )[0]